# validate select field depending on id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html like

```
<div class='form-field-box even' id="one_field_box">
    <div class='form-display-as-box' id="one_display_as_box">
        one<span class='required'>*</span>  :
    </div>
    <select id='one'  name='one'   data-placeholder="Select one" class="chzn-select"  style="width:300px;" tabindex="4">
      <option value='0'></option>
      <option value='Corto' selected='selected' >Corto</option>
      <option value='Largo'  >Largo</option>
    </select>               
    <div class="form-error"></div>
    <div class='clear'></div>   
</div>
```

And I have a script:

```
function validate(id, error) {
    var obj = $('#' + id);
    if(obj.val() == '0' || obj.val() == ''){
        obj.parent().parent().find('.form-error').html(error);
        return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

I call this function:

```
validate('one', "error in field one.");
```

I am not getting correct navigation, could you please help me correct validate() function ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not getting correct navigation"? What errors are you getting or what's not happening that you think should be?

Comment: well the message error is not displaying because it is not finding correct id="one"

Comment: @cMinor --> if you are not able to fin the correct id="one" make sure you give a context during selection using jquery i.e $('#'+id,'idofthecontext')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you're using some convention with your id's I would just construct the form id find it within that scope.

```
if(obj.val() === '0' || obj.val() === ''){

    $("#" + id + "_field_box .form-error").html(error)
    return true;
}
```

Added bonus is that if you change the position of your select you won't break the validation logic.

**Update**
I would also recommend using strict equality

Comment: How do I pass id parameter or where the function Knows I want `id="one"` to give an example...

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly but your **validate** function has an **id** param so i'm using that to construct the form id. Are you saying you won't have the id parameter available?

Comment: No wait, I tested And it works perfectly, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can try for get the correct target error message container. ***And you need to fire the `validate()` method by using any event handler.***

I think you need to fire the validate function on `select` change:

```
$('select.chzn-select').on('change', function() {
   validate( this.id, 'error in field '+ this.id +'.');
});


obj        // select#one
 .parent() // div.form-field-box
 .find('.form-error') // error viewer
 .html(error);
```

Or

```
obj       // select#one
 .next()  // div.form-field-box
 .find('.form-error') // error viewer
 .html(error);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're calling `validate()` after some event, eg. `change` or `submit` etc...

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/9CC2b/

Also, use `===` for strict comparisons:

```
if (obj.val() === '0' || obj.val() === '') {
```

To do validation for a group of elements, say `<select class="validateMe">` on a button click:

```
function validate(id, error) {
    var obj = $('#' + id);
    if (obj.val() === '0' || obj.val() === '') {
        obj.parent().parent().find('.form-error').append('<p>' + error + '</p>');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$('#validate').click(function () {
    $('.form-error').html('');    // clear existing errors
    $('select.validateMe').each(function () {
        var select = $(this);
        var id = $(this).attr('id');    // get id of each select
        validate(id, 'error in field ' + id);
    });
});
```

Comment: How could I call this to validate several fields depending on id?

Comment: @cMinor I add a selector to easily find the elements to validate, then run each of them through the `validate()` function. See http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/9CC2b/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jquery, utilize parent() method, with this even if in future you plan to add another wrapper over your dropdown this will still work.

```
function validate(id, error) {
    var obj = $('#' + id);
    if(obj.val() == '0' || obj.val() == ''){
        $('.form-error',obj.parent('#one_field_box')).html(error);
       return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: if I need to navigate through different `#one_field_box` i would need to pass those ids as parameters?

Comment: @cMinor first of all i would suggest refrain from using multiple elements with same id. instead provide them all the same class name and a data attribute to specify the error message ex:- data-error = "Name Cannot be empty" and then use $('.classname').each(call validate here with $(this)) remove the code var obj = $('#' + id); from your validate function and directly deal with the object and for error message get the message from $(obj).data('error').